# 4 Dimensional Array - C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, undefined-behavior, indexoutofrangeexception, variable-length-array

What is the problem with the following code? C compiler shows me `error: Segmentation fault`.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int n = 4;
    float A[n][n][n][n];
    A[n][n][1][1] = 1;
    A[n][n][1][2] = 0;
    A[n][n][1][3] = -3;
    A[n][n][1][4] = 0;
    A[n][n][2][1] = 1;
    A[n][n][2][2] = 0;
    A[n][n][2][3] = -3;
    A[n][n][2][4] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that it is execution of your program which triggers the segmentation fault. On my desktop [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) does not crash

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: *On my desktop GCC does not crash* probably because the optimizer removed everything since the local array is not used: https://godbolt.org/z/4qE7sK1cb

Comment: No: the compiler GCC does not crash. The *compiled executable* does crash. My experience is that GCC is crashing rarely (and I did contribute to it). It is difficult to have a `core` dumped by GCC

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: of course the execution of the program does... The OP has not yet learned the difference between compilation and execution, which does not exist for interpretive environments.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: interesting code to test my own toy compilers. I shall add a warning about the classic [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) for which you have an example in line 459...

Comment: @chqrlie: a more interesting code is of course [Pitrat's CAIA system](https://github.com/bstarynk/caia-pitrat). See also this [AFIA seminar](https://afia.asso.fr/journee-hommage-j-pitrat/)

Comment: @chqrlie: and if interested by compilers see also [CompCert](https://compcert.org/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: amazing work! and I am ashamed I was unaware of this 15 year old initiative from prominent French scientists at Inria and Orsay. I would have been proud to contribute had I not left academic research there 37 years ago :)

Comment: I happened to have met many times Jacques Pitrat. I miss him. And Xavier Leroy is at Collège de France.... (Pitrat was the director of my PhD jury)

Comment: You could be interested by the [books written by Jacques Pitrat](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Pitrat).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Too bad the Standard doesn't specify any means via which code can indicate that it is intended for a CompCertC compatible compiler, and that implementations must either process it correctly according to such semantics or reject it entirely, *with all other possible behaviors rendering an implementation non-conforming*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define an array of length N, the access to the last element is at the N-1 index, and the access to the first element is at index 0 because indexes start from 0 and end at N-1.

So your code should be like this:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<math.h>
#define N 4

int main() {
    float A[N][N][N][N];
    A[N-1][N-1][0][0]=1;
    A[N-1][N-1][0][1]=0;
    A[N-1][N-1][0][2]=-3;
    A[N-1][N-1][0][3]=0;
    A[N-1][N-1][1][0]=1;
    A[N-1][N-1][1][1]=0;
    A[N-1][N-1][1][2]=-3;
    A[N-1][N-1][1][3]=0;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you're using a variable to define the length of your array, which is good only in the [C99 standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/99) and onwards. If you don't need a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (variable length array), you should use the #define instead.

Answer (score 4):

All these assignments access memory outside the defined variable length  array.

```
A[n][n][1][1]=1;
A[n][n][1][2]=0;
A[n][n][1][3]=-3;
A[n][n][1][4]=0;
A[n][n][2][1]=1;
A[n][n][2][2]=0;
A[n][n][2][3]=-3;
A[n][n][2][4]=0;
```

That is the valid range of indices for each dimension of the array is `[0, n )`. Thus the expression `A[n]` is invalid.

It seems you mean the following assignments

```
A[0][0][0][0]=1;
A[0][0][0][1]=0;
A[0][0][0][2]=-3;
A[0][0][0][3]=0;
A[0][0][1][0]=1;
A[0][0][1][1]=0;
A[0][0][1][2]=-3;
A[0][0][1][3]=0;
```

Comment: While the answer is correct I think it could  be improved in two ways: (1) Mention the technical term "zero-based" array (or perhaps array indexing); and (2) I'm afraid that some readers may not notice the subtlety of "[0,n)" -- it would be clearer if "n-1" appeared somewhere in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n=4;
float A[n][n][n][n];
A[n][n][1][1]=1;
```

is not valid in every C standard (read [n1570](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or better). You may want to code `const int n=4;` or `#define n 4`

(on cheap microcontrollers you might not even have enough stack space for 256 floats -> possible stack overflow)

And then, **you *always* have a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)** (read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). In `A[x][x][1][1]` the valid indexes are from `x` being 0 to `x` being 3 -that is `n-1` - (not 4).

You might want to code

```
A[n-1][n-1][1][1] = 1;
```

but you should know that `A[0][0][0][0]` is being uninitialized. It may contain garbage (signalling NaN), and an hypothetical `printf("%f\n", A[0][0][0][0]);` could fail ....

I guess that [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) would have caught your mistake (I leave you to check that). Be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

I would initialize `A` with zeros (to ease debugging, and to have more reproducible runs) -after having corrected the buffer overflow-:

```
float A[n][n][n][n]={0.0};
```

Comment: `const int n=4;` doesn't change a thing.

Comment: I did not wrote that it changes something. I think that `float A[n][n][n][n];` is invalid in C89 and probably C99

Comment: It is valid in C99 and conditionally valid in C11 and onwards.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Using const int n=4; is equivalent to int n=4; for declaring a variable length array.:)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This declaration float A[n][n][n][n]={}; is invalid in C even when n is an integer constant expression.